# Detect which async overload is called inside a C# method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, mono.cecil

Using reflection, I need to determine which overloads a particular async method is calling. In this case, I need to inspect the `DoSomething()` method to determine which method calls to `MyMethod()` it's making.

First, consider the following C# console app for the sync version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Mono.Cecil;

namespace CecilReflection
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            var toInspect = assemblyDefinition.MainModule
                .GetTypes()
                .SelectMany(type => type.Methods
                    .Where(method => method.HasBody)
                    .Select(method => new
                    {
                        Type = type,
                        Method = method
                    }))
                .Where(x => x.Method.Name == "DoSomething");

            foreach (var entry in toInspect)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\tType = {entry.Type.Name}\n\t\tMethod = {entry.Method.Name}");
                foreach (var instruction in entry.Method.Body.Instructions)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{instruction.OpCode} \"{instruction.Operand}\"");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            myClass.MyMethod();
            myClass.MyMethod(5);
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public void MyMethod()
            {
            }

            public void MyMethod(int arg)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
        Type = Program
                Method = DoSomething
nop ""
newobj "System.Void CecilReflection.Program/MyClass::.ctor()"
stloc.0 ""
ldloc.0 ""
callvirt "System.Void CecilReflection.Program/MyClass::MyMethod()"
nop ""
ldloc.0 ""
ldc.i4.5 ""
callvirt "System.Void CecilReflection.Program/MyClass::MyMethod(System.Int32)"
nop ""
ret ""
```

By looking at the `callvirt` entries, I'm able to detect that both overloads of `MyMethod()` are called using the above code.

Here's the async version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Mono.Cecil;

namespace CecilReflection
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            var toInspect = assemblyDefinition.MainModule
                .GetTypes()
                .SelectMany(type => type.Methods
                    .Where(method => method.HasBody)
                    .Select(method => new
                    {
                        Type = type,
                        Method = method
                    }))
                .Where(x => x.Method.Name == "DoSomething");

            foreach (var entry in toInspect)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\tType = {entry.Type.Name}\n\t\tMethod = {entry.Method.Name}");
                foreach (var instruction in entry.Method.Body.Instructions)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{instruction.OpCode} \"{instruction.Operand}\"");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            await myClass.MyMethodAsync();
            await myClass.MyMethodAsync(5);
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public async Task MyMethodAsync()
            {
            }

            public async Task MyMethodAsync(int arg)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
        Type = Program
                Method = DoSomething
newobj "System.Void CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1::.ctor()"
stloc.0 ""
ldloc.0 ""
call "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Create()"
stfld "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1::<>t__builder"
ldloc.0 ""
ldc.i4.m1 ""
stfld "System.Int32 CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1::<>1__state"
ldloc.0 ""
ldflda "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1::<>t__builder"
ldloca.s "V_0"
call "System.Void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start<CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1>(!!0&)"
ldloc.0 ""
ldflda "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder CecilReflection.Program/<DoSomething>d__1::<>t__builder"
call "System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::get_Task()"
ret ""
```

With the async version, I'm not able to determine anything about which overloads to `MyMethodAsync()` were called, if any.

Is there any way to determine which overloads to `MyMethodAsync()` were called? It's not a requirement that I use Mono.Cecil, but I've had even less luck using `System.Reflection` to accomplish this. If a completely different approach would work, that's fine.

Comment: In case of `async`, you're reflecting over the wrong thing -- the actual code now lives in the state machine class (`Program/<DoSomething>d__1`) and from there in the `.MoveNext` method. Embedding knowledge of the way the compiler constructs async state machines is not an attractive prospect, though (even if it's very coarse knowledge like "let's check all the methods in this strange class") -- this is 100 times easier to do if the source is available, as then you can just use Roslyn.

Comment: an async method is [transformed into a class by the compiler.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) So, you will need to digg deeper. This seem an awful lot of work. Might I ask why you are trying to do this?

Comment: We're automatically building out API documentation, and due to how we have things implemented, we can be 100% sure of which response codes a route will return based on which overload is called inside a given controller method.